# How to get index page for specific group id in other Controller Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have groups each group have unique id. there is button shown in supervisor index page for reports. that button beside each group that route to different index in other controller that named Weeklyreports. So i want if the supervisor click this button for specific group it should bring only that reports that belong to this group, and he can create reports that belong to the same group id.

Before it was when he click the button its just route him to entire weeklyreports index and display whole table records.

Now i am trying to pass group id in the url when he click the button its pass show Page Not found.
This is the URL i have try it **/weeklyreports/91**.

**Here is reports button in index.blabe for groups**

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ URL::to('weeklyreports',$group_id) }}">Weekly Report</a>
```

**index function in WeeklyreportController:**

```
public function index()
{
    $weeklyreports = Weeklyreport::latest()->paginate(5);
    return view('weeklyreports.index',compact('weeklyreports'))
        ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
}
```

**create funcation in WeeklyReportController:**

```
 public function create(Group $group)
{
    return view('weeklyreports.create');
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request , Group $group, gp_groups $gp_groups)
{
    request()->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'date' => 'required',
        'time' => 'required',
        'work_sub' => 'required',
        'work_under' => 'required',
        'issue' => 'required',
        'topic' => 'required',
        'work_std' => 'required',
        'next_date' => 'required',
        'next_time' => 'required',
    ]);

    $users= Auth::user();
    $data= $request->all();
    $weeklyreport = new Weeklyreport;

    
    $weeklyreport->name=$data['name'];
    $weeklyreport->date=$data['date'];
    $weeklyreport->time=$data['time'];
    $weeklyreport->work_sub=$data['work_sub'];
    $weeklyreport->work_under=$data['work_under'];
    $weeklyreport->issue=$data['issue'];
    $weeklyreport->topic=$data['topic'];
    $weeklyreport->work_std=$data['work_std'];
    $weeklyreport->next_date=$data['next_date'];
    $weeklyreport->next_time=$data['next_time'];
    
    // $weeklyreport->gpid=$gp_groups->gpid;

    
    $weeklyreport->save();

    

    $rr=DB::table('weeklyreports')->orderBy('created_at','desc')->first();

    
    

//insert into attendance table
$student_id = [];
          foreach ($request->student_id as $key=>$id){
              $student_id[] = [
                  'week_id'=>$weeklyreport->id,
                  'student_id'=>$id,

              ];
          }



 DB::table('attendance')->insert($student_id);

    //Weeklyreport::create($request->all());

    return redirect()->route('weeklyreports.index')
                    ->with('success','Weeklyreport created successfully.');
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/weeklyreports/{group_id}', [WeeklyreportController::class, 'index']);
```

Comment: Do you have a route for `WeeklyReportController`'s `create` method?

Comment: Yes i have in index.blade there is button route to create method

Comment: I mean in web.php. Do you have defined a route?

Comment: No in web.php i have route like this                                      
 Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {
    
    Route::resource('weeklyreports', WeeklyreportController::class);
      
});

Answer (score 0):

You will need to access your route parameter in your controller method.

Here is the Laravel documentation for reference: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-parameters

You should be able to access your parameter as follows:

```
public function index(int $groupId) { ... }
```

Enabling you to then use this in your query (assuming `gpid` is the correct group id column)

```
public function index(int $groupId) 
{
    $weeklyreports = Weeklyreport::latest()
        ->where('gpid', $groupId) // <- Utilising the route parameter to filter results
        ->paginate(5);
    
    return view('weeklyreports.index', compact('weeklyreports'))
        ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
}
```